# Moving to other game states with ScreenManager

Tags: c#

I'm creating a game in C#, and I've created a `ScreenManager` so I can call

```
ScreenManager.MoveToScreen(typeof(ScreenClassHere))
```

to move to other game states. However, I feel that my method of creating an instance of the class is... not very optimal. See for yourself.

```
    public static void MoveToScreen(Type s)
    {
        if (currentscreen != null) currentscreen.Remove();

        currentscreen = (Screen)s.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
        currentscreen.Init();
    }
```

Does anyone know if there's a better way to create an instance of a certain class from a `Type`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use generics

```
public static void MoveToScreen<T>() where T : Screen, new()
{
    if (currentscreen != null) currentscreen.Remove();

    currentscreen = new T();
    currentscreen.Init();
}
```

In this case, you'd have to call the method as

```
ScreenManager.MoveToScreen<ScreenClassHere>();
```

Comment: Let's get those proper casts in there. :)

Comment: Although this seems like the better way to do it, I'm getting errors about the compiler not being able to convert T to Screen...  `Error 1 Cannot convert type 'T' to 'SFMLGame.Screens.Screen'`

Comment: Since `currentscreen` seems to have the type `Screen` this should be `where T : Screen, new()`.

Comment: @sepp2k - Exactly I was gonna suggest that over an awkward cast `currentscreen = (Screen)(object)new T();`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like the naming of a `Remove` method, it suggests that you remove something from the `currentScreen` but really it's the method that is called when the `currentScreen` itself is being removed, if I got it right.

Also, other people suggesting generics are correct, you should use it. But if you once again find yourself in need of creating an instance knowing its type, don't go `GetConstructors` way. Use `Activator.CreateInstance` for that.

Answer (score 4):

Nitpicky, but I would change `if (currentscreen != null) currentscreen.Remove();` to

```
if (currentscreen != null) {
   currentscreen.Remove();
}
```

I second pdr on using generics.

Comment: I don't like the unnecessary braces but I don't like it as a one-liner either, I would make it a two-liner with proper indentation. Just an opinion

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing that either. I started always using braces because it's clearer to modify. Personal preference :)